# Laravel hasOne can't only one attribute from the relation model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Model called User That has one to many relation with orders
I'm trying to get using an eloquent relation  the first order date he did

I tried adding in the User Model

```
public function firstOrderDate(){
return $this->hasOne(Order::class)->oldest();
}
```

My Query

```
User::whereHas('firstOrderDate')->with('firstOrderDate')->get()
```

it's returning the Whole Order model
I even tried to add select('date') it's returning null now

Comment: Post your controller code here.

Comment: I posted it the problem I want to return the date from the order model only rather than the whole model

Comment: Try this `User::with('firstOrderDate', function($query) {
 $query->first();
})->get();`

Comment: try `->value('date')` for specific field like `$this->hasOne(Order::class)->oldestOfMany()->value('date');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by creating a relationship for first order and create accessor for first_order date

```
public function firstOrder(){
    return $this->hasOne(Order::class)->oldestOfMany();
}

public function getFirstOrderDateAttribute($value){
    !empty($this->firstOrder) ? $this->firstOrder->created_at : '';
}
```

Your Query will be:

```
User::whereHas('firstOrder')->selectRaw('users.*, "" as first_order_date')->get();
```

Comment: laravel 5 doesn't have `oldestOfMany` method (i believe it introduced in 8)

Answer (score 0):

> it's returning the Whole Order model I even tried to add select('date') it's returning null now

to work properly relation need relation key to be selected

```php
User::whereHas('firstOrderDate')->with(['firstOrderDate' => function($q) {
    $q->select('user_id', 'date_field');
})->get()
```

then you will get shrinked `Order` model with only selected fields like this

```php
{
    'id': 1,
    // other fields
    'firstOrderDate': {
        'user_id': 1,
        'date_field': '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
    }
}
```

upd: you didn't mention where result goes, so

1. if its going to blade you can simply use `{{optional($user->firstOrderDate)->date_field}}` or create a getter something like

```php
//user model
// be careful with naming collisions - don't create getter for relation
public function getFirstOrderDateTimeAttribute() {
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('firstOrderDate') {
        return null; // to prevent n+1 requests problem
    }
    // optional just in case
    return optional($this->firstOrderDate)->date_field;    
}
```

and do `{{$user->firstOrderDateTime}}`

2. if its api response i'd recommend you to check [api resources docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#introduction) - very helpful thing to separate response fields from models fields, so you can set `first_order_date` field to be filled from relation object like

Comment: Thank you for the answer though it doesn't solve my problem as I want to only have firsOrderDate:'1970-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: @Zein check edited answer

Answer (score -1):

This could do the job (didn't test it):

```
public function firstOrderDate(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class)->oldest()->first()->firstOrderDate;
}
```

You said, you have a one to many relationship with the order table, so use hasMany, sort by oldest first and return first Model and get the attribute 'firstOrderDate'.

Comment: you can use hasOne to get one of them this is not the issue I'm getting the oldest model but I want to get one property

Comment: This function will get you a single property. You get the property by it's name: in this case I used firstOrderDate as property name, deducting it from your question. But it could be anything else.

Comment: tried it gave me an error

Comment: *An error* such as ... I'd like to learn something, too.